Extract first day with temperature higher than 15 C in ERA5 Land GEE
I have loaded the ERA5 land temperature data at 2 m height in Google Earth Engine. Now I want to find the first day where the temperature is greater than 15 degrees Celsius globally between January 01, 2001 and January 01, 2002.
I have done this:
// Load the ERA5 Land daily aggregated dataset for the year 2001
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/DAILY_AGGR')
                .filterDate('2001-01-01', '2002-01-01')
                .select('temperature_2m');

var mask = dataset.gt(0.15);
var filter = mask.updateMask(mask).multiply(dataset).first();

However, this expects that the dataset is one singular image, while it is a series of 365 images. I want to extract, on a pixel basis, the first day of the year when the temperature is greater than 15 degrees.
I want to get a global map of the day of the year, hence, the index of the series with a value > 15.
How do I do this in GEE?

Here's how I would approach this:

Add a band to each image with the integer day-of-year.
In each image, mask all pixels below the temperature threshold.
Calculate the minimum remaining (unmasked) value over the collection to get the first DOY over the threshold.

You can add the DOY band (starting at 1) with:
var with_doy = dataset.map(function(img) {
  var doy = img.date().getRelative("day", "year").add(1);
  var doyBand = ee.Image.constant(doy).uint16().rename('doy');
  return img.addBands(doyBand);
})

Then you can mask pixels below the 15 deg C threshold (converted to 288.15 Kelvin) using:
var above_threshold = with_doy.map(function(img) {
  return img.updateMask(img.select("temperature_2m").gt(288.15).selfMask());
});

Finally you can calculate the minimum value in the doy band. Because pixels below the threshold are masked, this will give you the first day over the threshold.
var first_doy_above_threshold = above_threshold.select("doy").reduce(ee.Reducer.min());

Note that any pixel that never exceeded the threshold will be masked in the output.
